# Request scope issue in IBM portal 8.0

Tags: jsf-2, portlet, websphere-portal, jsr286

I have a JSR 286 portlet running in a Websphere Portal Server 8.0. There, I do a file upload and after show the results of processing. Initially my managed bean responsible to process this file has a Request Scope (@RequestScoped). When I Click in command button to upload file, the method in MB process correctly and fills a collection of results (dadosCarga attribute in MB below) that must be showed in JSP page. However, when I the page is rederized I got a stacktrace explaining that my Managed Bean class was not found (ClassNotFoundException) and results are not shown. I got the same results using ViewScoped. Just when I changed scope from Request to Session (@SessionScoped), the results are shown.

After I [googled](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=jsf+portlet+request+scope) for some answer, I found [this page](http://www.liferay.com/pt/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2202539) explaining about difference between action and render request in Portlets. It was suggested to use [JSF Portlet bridge](https://jsfportletbridge.dev.java.net/). However, this page is not active anymore. There is a [Portlet bridge for Apache Myfaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/portlet-bridge/) (IBM portal runs over MyFaces). However, I could not see how use it. Is it just put both jars (api and implementation) in WEB-INF/lib? I tried, but I got a exception when I tried load the pages in application. So I remove them.

Below, I show My Portlet configuration, Managed Bean and JSP page. Is there any alternative, a better Idea about how to deal with this? Or may be a explanation about how to use correclty MyFaces Bridge (I could not found none in its home page).

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

*Portlet configuration*:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>CargaUsuarios</portlet-name>
    <display-name>CargaUsuarios</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>com.ibm.faces.portlet.page.view</name>
        <value>/pages/carga/cargaUsuarios.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>wps.markup</name>
        <value>html</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>Carga de Usuarios</title>
        <short-title>Carga deUsuarios</short-title>
        <keywords>Carga Usuario</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
</portlet>
```

*Manged Bean*:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cargaUsuariosMB")
@RequestScoped
public class CargaUsuariosMB extends AbstractMB {

    private String nomeArquivo; // FIle name

    private Collection<CargaUsuarioInfoBean> dadosCarga; // processing result.

    public String doUploadArquivo() {
        this.dadosCarga = ... // process file and receives a collection 

        this.nomeArquivo = ... // get uploaded file name

        return null; // Return to same origin page
    }

    // Getters...

}
```

*JSP page (cargaUsuarios.jsp)*:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@taglib
    uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/portal/v6.1/portlet-client-model"
    prefix="portlet-client-model"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet-client-model:init>
    <portlet-client-model:require module="ibm.portal.xml.*" />
    <portlet-client-model:require module="ibm.portal.portlet.*" />
</portlet-client-model:init>
<f:view>
    <h2>Carga de Usuários</h2>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            <label for="arquivoCarga"> <span>File:</span> </label> <input
                type="file" name="arquivoCarga" id="FileCarga" />
        </p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Salvar File"
                    action="#{cargaUsuariosMB.doUploadArquivo}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="pnlProcessamento"
        rendered="#{not empty cargaUsuariosMB.dadosCarga }">
        <h:outputText
            value="Dados do File #{cargaUsuariosMB.nomeArquivo} processados com sucesso."></h:outputText>
        <br />
        <h:dataTable id="tblDadosProcessamento"
            columnClasses="numLinha,cpf,status"
            value="#{cargaUsuariosMB.dadosCarga}" var="dadosCarga"
            styleClass="dadosProcessamento" width="100%" border="1">
            <%-- Show processing results. --%>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:messages styleClass="messages" id="msgsPesquisaCadastro"
        errorClass="mensagensErro" errorStyle="color: red;"></h:messages>
</f:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding the following in the portlet.xml and see if it works:

```
<container-runtime-option>
    <name>javax.portlet.actionScopedRequestAttributes</name>
    <value>true</value>
</container-runtime-option>
```

For more information please download and check the following section in Portlet V2.0 specification:
PLT.10.4.4 Runtime Option
javax.portlet.actionScopedRequestAttributes

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the render and action request, JSF (or CDI) Request and ViewScoped doesn't work properly. But solution could be using [JBoss Portlet Bridge](http://www.jboss.org/portletbridge) which contains brand new scopes - PortletLifecycleScoped and PortletRedisplayScoped. The first will behave exactly like a RequestScope, you will find more info in the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/GTNPORTAL36/Portlet+CDI+Scopes). However, I am not sure if will able to use these scopes in other portals except GateIn.

Answer (score 0):

When you use request scope, the data needs to be carried from portlet action to portlet render phase. The data is normally carried for request scoped beans via the portlet render parameters are a String. In order to get your data saved there, your object needs to be Serializable.

Besides that, you might want to upgrade your WebSphere Application Server beneath the WebSphere Portal to version 8.0.0.6 to avoid [PM79460](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM79460) and Portal itself to the latest FixPack as well.

Hope this helps.

BTW: JSR286 and JEE6 do not specify how CDI shall interact with the Portlet programming model. You might want to look at [JSR362](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=362) for that.

Answer (score 0):

IBM uses its own portlet bridge. It is not recommended to use any bridges in addition to that.